# Xamarin Android Urban Airship - push was working, now not

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, urbanairship.com

I had everything set up correctly, now all of a sudden I'm not getting Android Push notifications.   I'm using Xamarin Android.  Was working last week.  I checked everything

- device has push enabled
- setup google gcm key and package in urban airship
- call takeoff on start
  -set up airship.properties in app
  -in firebase console, I have the right debug sha1 fingerprint

EDIT:  I looked up my channel ID for my app and noticed

Push Notification Opt-in:
Opted-out

How did this happen?  I set the device to accept notifications for this app

Answer (score 1):

Do you have application logs on the device? Enable verbose logging by setting the appropriate log level in the airship config. You should see something like:

> Updating channel with payload:
>   {"channel":{"opt_in":true,"device_type":"android","background":true,"tags":["notification_test"],"set_tags":true,"push_address":"PUSH_ADDRESS"}}

That will let you verify if the device is actually opted in or not. If opted out, double check push and notifications are enabled, and verify you have a push address.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't see that message in the log, however I see Airship launch, and Airship Ready.  I see the channel in the UA dashboard under Android Channels. It has a push address.  There are two entries for the same channel ID, both with the same info.  Would the 'Updating channel' message appear when the app is launched?

Comment: Ok, this is weird.  I uninstalled, then reinstalled the app and now the push works.  Any idea how the device 'opted out' without me doing anything?

Comment: @PatrickGoode - reinstalling it would cause your channel to be recreated. Not sure why your channel would be opted out on its own. If you are not seeing the logs you need to set developmentLogLevel to VERBOSE.

Comment: @PatrickGoode If you contact support they can help dig into why the channel was opted-out if you have your old channelID.

Comment: Thanks @ralepinski.  I posted in their forums.  They're not sure why the channel got opted out